# How to add a new line in a formula referenced area in an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to insert a new line and do other operations with cells that are referenced by a different cell.

E.g. `C1=SUM(A1:A5)`

If a new line is inserted at `A3`, Excel wouldm automatically redefine `C1` as `C1=SUM(A1:A6)`.

Openpyxl is not able to do this redefinition. What are the options except for a cumbersome manual redefinition?
I have read of xlwings but is it the only option as I am not sure about its license..?

Comment: Use the tokeniser to adjust the formula. Sorry, if you think that's cumbersome but it's an awful lot less cumbersom than maintaining the kind of dependency graph that Excel does.